# Why when moving an object towards a target if the target is far away the object move very fast but if the target is close it's moving slower?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want it to move slower like in close range objects.

The small cube is moving from the player hand to the right large cube.
The right large cube is the target.

[image: Target moving slower smooth]

This is the player root object with the script attached to it the Throw Speed is set to 0.5f

[image: The script attached]

This is the script in the Update I'm calling the ThrowObject method :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableItem[] lookObj = null;
    public GameObject objToThrow;
    public Text text;
    public Text textMultiLine;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public float maxDistance = 10f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = true;
    public float throwSpeed;

    private List<InteractableItem> allDetectedItems;
    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private Quaternion savedRotation;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;
    private InteractableItem target;
    private bool throwObj = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        allDetectedItems = new List<InteractableItem>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            allDetectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                //if (lookAt.magnitude > maxDistance) continue;
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                    allDetectedItems.Add(target);
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);

                    // -> new code block
                    if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                    {
                        // call your funtion to shoot something here
                        throwObj = true;
                        target = primaryTarget;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show primary object found by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null) text.text = "Item found: " + primaryTarget.description;
            else text.text = "Item found: none";

            // Show all objects found by the player
            if (allDetectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                string result = "";
                foreach (InteractableItem item in allDetectedItems)
                {
                    result += item.description + "\n";
                }
                textMultiLine.text = result;
            }
            else
            {
                textMultiLine.text = "No items found.";
            }
        }
    }

    private void ThrowObject()
    {
        objToThrow.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(objToThrow.transform.position, target.transform.position, throwSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (throwObj == true)
        {
            ThrowObject();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when the player is facing the big far space ship and the cube is moving to the space ship it's moving very fast I almost can't see the cube moving. Not sure why it's moving slowly smooth to close targets but very fast to far targets ?

Comment: As @Максим Фисман suggested I would use `Vector3.MoveTowards` instead of `Vector3.Lerp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moving you use function [Vector3.Lerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html). It finds the interectabke value between `a` and `b` using a `formula: a + (b - a) * t`.

let's assume that the z-position doesn't matter and a main object position *[0,0]*
Let's look at the following situations:

- The target object is **next to** the main one. Its position is *[10, 10]*.
  Our main object moves from start position to target position by variable `float t`. Let's count the main object's position if `t` is, for example: `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3` (obviously that if it is `0` the main object's position is start position, and if it is `1` the main object's position is target position:
  **FORMULA: a + (b - a) * t**

```
    1) [0,0] + ([10,10] - [0,0]) * 0.1 = [0,0] + [10,10]*0.1 = [0,0] + [1,1] = [1,1]
    2) [0,0] + ([10,10] - [0,0]) * 0.2 = [0,0] + [10,10]*0.2 = [0,0] + [2,2] = [2,2]
    3) [0,0] + ([10,10] - [0,0]) * 0.3 = [0,0] + [10,10]*0.3 = [0,0] + [3,3] = [3,3]
```

We get, that changing the variable `t` by **0.1** causes the position to change by **[1,1]** units.

- The target object is *50* times farther that in the first occasion. Its position is now *[500,500]*. And we leave `t` as it was: `0.1 and 0.2 and 0.3`. Count:
  **FORMULA: a + (b - a) * t**

```
    1) [0,0] + ([500,500] - [0,0]) * 0.1 = [0,0] + [500,500]*0.1 = [0,0] + [50,50] = [50,50]
    2) [0,0] + ([500,500] - [0,0]) * 0.2 = [0,0] + [500,500]*0.2 = [0,0] + [100,100] = [100,100]
    3) [0,0] + ([500,500] - [0,0]) * 0.3 = [0,0] + [500,500]*0.3 = [0,0] + [150,150] = [150,150]
```

Here the cahnging the variable `t` by **0.1** causes the position to change by **[50,50]** units.

THUS, the greater the distance between objects is, the faster the main object's position changes.

Well, it was the explanation of what you do incorrect. Now the decision:

You ought to use a function [transform.Translate(Vector3 translation)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html). 
This function moves the object in the direction of parameter Vector3 translate. Of course if translation equals to [1,0,0] the object moves to positive x, if [-1,0,0] - to negative x, if [0,1,0] - to positive y, if [0,-1,0] - to negative y and et cetera.

How to get this Vector3 `translation`? You must substract the your object's position from target position. And then you should normalize it (so that the values were not more than 1 and not less than 0). Code looks so:

```
Vector3 dir; // direction of moving. This parameter will be given to the function Translate()
GameObject targetPosition; // Target position
float speed; // The speed of moving. Recommended to be set from inspector
private void ThrowObject () {
    dir = targetPosition - transform.position;
    transform.Traslate(dir.normalized*Time.deltaTime*speed);
}
private void Update () {
    ThrowObject();
}
```

P.S. We multiply `dir` by `Time.deltaTime` to make the speed of moving the same on both fast and slow computers (tablets PCs, phones...)

Comment: Or you may use Vector3.MoveTowards. Probably.